# Understanding composite functions

Tags: functions

I have the below example of a function(s):

```
Let  ∶  → ℤ be the length function, such that:

    () = the number of characters in , ∀ ∈ .

Let  ∶ ℤ → {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} ∶  () =  mod 8, ∀ ∈ ℤ. 

For example:
 (5) = 5 mod 8 = 5 and  (25) = 25 mod 8 = 1.
```

The three questions in regards to the above are:
1. L(hippopotamus)
2. T(30)
3. (T∘L)(dodecahedron)

My understanding is the first function is returning the length of a word, ie. the number of characters in that word. The second function is returning the remainder of  modulo 8, T(10) would be 2.

Therefore am I correct in thinking the last question is a function within a function? T(L(dodecahedron)), therefore the output of L(x) would be the input of T(x)?

```
(T∘L)(dodecahedron) = 4
```

However, I am not understanding `Let  ∶ ℤ → {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`, what does this part mean?

Comment: There is an error in the statement of the question.  The second function should either read $R: \mathbb{Z} \to \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ defined by $R(n) = n \mod{8}, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $T: \mathbb{Z} \to \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ defined by $T(n) = n \mod{8}, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Im not suprised, most of my universities coursework is like this :/ I'll let them know

Answer (score 0):

{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} is a set containing 8 elements, the whole numbers between 0 and 7.  ∶ ℤ → {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} means that R is a funtion which takes a whole number as an argument and returns a whole number between 0 and 7.

Comment: how does it come into play int he above case, and what does that mean by taking a whole number and returning a whole number? R(7) = 7?, apologies im super new to the math side of programming.

Comment: I'll give you a few examples of what taking argument and returning means. R(5)=5 (R toke 5 as an argument and returned 5), R(15)=7 (R toke 15 as an argument and returned 7), R(1000)=0 (R toke 1000 as an argument and returned 0).